# What's the difference between Flux pattern and Mediator pattern?

Tags: reactjs, redux, design-patterns, flux, mediator

Is there a difference between the two patterns of flux and mediator?
And isn't redux a mediator pattern?

Redux, a representative implementation of the Flux pattern, has a single store in the center that allows components to pass events through action without having to exchange data directly between components, where reducer is used to process events, notify each component of these changes and trigger rendering.

I think Redux is a pattern that uses two types of observer pattern and Mediator pattern.

I think flux pattern is a one-way binding of data from Mediator pattern.

Comment: Looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern - flux is much more concrete and detailed than the mediator pattern. Mediator pattern seems to describe a very vague, abstract way of putting a "mediator" between the communication of two objects. That term honestly never comes up in modern JS frontend discussions, I wouldn't pay too much attention to it. It might be more relevant for OOP-heavy languages. Also your question might be better off on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/